Xlib の XAllocColorCells() 関数で2つのプライベートカラーセルを割り当てるには？
Xlibを用いたプログラミングで、2つのプライベートカラーセルを割り当てようと以下のコードを書きました。
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    Display *display;
    Window parent, window;
    int screen;
    Colormap cmap;
    unsigned long plane_mask, pixels[2];
    int border, background;

    display = XOpenDisplay( "" );
    if ( !display ) {
                fprintf( stderr, "XOpenDisplay error\n" );
                exit( 1 );
    }

    screen = DefaultScreen( display );
    parent = RootWindow( display, screen );
    cmap = DefaultColormap( display, screen );

    if ( !XAllocColorCells( display, cmap, False,
                                &plane_mask, 0, pixels, 2 ) ) {
            fprintf( stderr, "XAllocColorCells error\n" );
            printf( "%s\n", strerror( errno ) );
            exit( 1 );
    }

    getchar();

}

するとビルドは正常に通るのですが、実行時に XAllocColorCells() の部分でプライベートカラーセルの割り当てに失敗し、自らコーディングしたエラーメッセージ"XAllocColorCells error"が表示されプログラムが終了してしまいます。
XAllocColorCells()の戻り値は0で、エラーメッセージは以下です。
XAllocColorCells error
Resource temporarily unavailable

XAllocColorCells() を用いて2つのプライベートカラーセルを正常に割り当てるようにするにはどのように書けばいいでしょうか、ご教示お願いいたします。
環境は、
↓OSのバージョン
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
↓GNOMEのバージョン
GNOME Shell 46.0
以上です。よろしくお願い致します。

XAllocColorCells()の返り値を確認し、質問文に追記すると回答を得られやすくなると思います。(返り値はmanページ参照(例: https://ja.manpages.org/xalloccolorcells/3)

参考にさせていただきます。

「XAllocColorCells() の戻り値は1です」と書かれていますが、XAllocColor(3) では XAllocColorCells returns nonzero if it succeeded or zero if it failed. となっていますので、実際には 0 が返っているかと思います。また、実際のエラー内容を確認する場合は errno.h と string.h を include して、if ( !XAllocColorCells( display, ...){ ... } ブロックの内側に printf("%s\n", strerror(errno) ); を追加する必要があります。

参考にさせていただいきます、また質問を編集します。あと戻り値が1と書いていたのは間違いでした。申し訳ございません。

おそらく、カラーマップが TrueColor なのだと思います。そのため、XAllocColorCells() で色を割り当てる必要がありません。（TrueColor の場合、color pixel の値がRGB値そのものになっているからです）
